# Javascript Error in Nginx but not Apache

Tags: javascript, apache, nginx, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

After switching to Nginx, I've noticed a console error "unexpected end of file" in Chrome. The exact same file is fine though if served via Apache though. I tested by loading it from another domain being served by Apache.

The file is "uglified" using [grunt uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) and what's interesting is when I skip this, it's parsed fine when served by Nginx. So Nginx seems to be breaking the uglified version only in some way.

Comment: Chrome will be pointing you at where it thinks the problem is. That information is likely to be a *really big clue*, both to you and to us. Without that information, this question can't really be answered except by guessing.

Comment: The problem is the file is minified so the line number isn't helpful. Then when I un-minified it the issue goes! Very strange...

Comment: Right. I'm saying, if you click the error, Chrome will show you the line **and character** where the problem occurs, even if that's character 33,456 on line 1.

Comment: Chrome points to the last characters, it says "unexpected end of file" referring to "}]);" Except that doesn't really help, as those characters need to be there. When I view the minified file on the server, use Javascript Beautify to un-minify it. Without changing any characters, it works..

Comment: does that mean that nginx somehow doesn't serve the whole file? like it stops in the middle ?

Comment: Nope, the whole file is being served. I can actually copy and paste the same file contents that are served fine by apache, but when served by nginx it results in a JS error.